# Wrap API Json response in Go

Tags: json, dictionary, go, wrapper

I am sorry if this is a silly question because i am very new in Go.
I am calling couple of apis on the base of business logic, different types of response coming like json array, nest json and single json object.
i need to wrap a api response that called according to business logic in a common format like:

```
{
"data":"api response here",
"statusCode":200
}
```

i tried some but its not expect output

```
type Model[T any] struct {
    Data       T
    StatusCode int
}

model := Model[string]{Data: apiResponse, StatusCode: 200}
out, err := json.Marshal(model)
```

out put of this code is

```
{
    "Data": "[{\"name\":\"Harry Potter\",\"city\":\"London\"},{\"name\":\"Don Quixote\",\"city\":\"Madrid\"},{\"name\":\"Joan of Arc\",\"city\":\"Paris\"},{\"name\":\"Rosa Park\",\"city\":\"Alabama\"}]",
    "StatusCode": 200
}
```

this i made these changes

```
var result []map[string]interface{} 
json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &result) 
out, err := json.Marshal(result)
```

output was as expected, above api response was in proper json when use `[]map[string]interface`
problem is, its only for those api that return array of json. those apis returning single json object then to make it work i need to do this

```
map[string]interface`
```

means remove the array map.
i need to make it generic so that any kind of json response map into it.

Answer (score 1):

Use type of field `Data` as an `interface{}`

```
type APIResponse struct {
    Data       interface{} `json:"data"`
    StatusCode int         `json:"statusCode"`
}
```

And then you can assign any API Response type to the `Data` field and marshal it.

```
func main() {
    r := []Person{
        {
            Name: "Harry Porter",
            City: "London",
        },
        {
            Name: "Don Quixote",
            City: "Madrid",
        },
    }

    res := APIResponse{
        Data:       r,
        StatusCode: 200,
    }

    resByt, err := json.Marshal(res)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(resByt))
}
```

Output

```
{"data":[{"name":"Harry Porter","city":"London"},{"name":"Don Quixote","city":"Madrid"}],"statusCode":200}
```

Run the full code here in [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/8RXatQRkqHe).

Comment: thanks for your answer. This answer solve my half of problem but still i am unable to decode string json api response. To decode that json var result []map[string]interface{} use this for array json and var result map[string]interface{} this for single json object. I want some thing that will work for both without changing any this

Comment: You need to check whether the response data field type is a struct or slice. Then you can use `[]map[string]interface{}` for slices and `map[string]interface{}` for struct. refer to the [playground example](https://go.dev/play/p/CeQwkIg2_tI).

Comment: Thanks for you details answer but my api response is in string array  json "[{\"name\":\"Harry Potter\",\"city\":\"London\"},{\"name\":\"Don Quixote\",\"city\":\"Madrid\"},{\"name\":\"Joan of Arc\",\"city\":\"Paris\"},{\"name\":\"Rosa Park\",\"city\":\"Alabama\"}]"  this ill unmarshall with this way []map[string]interface{}     and other api response is string single json object "{\"country\":\"dubai\",\"region\":\"Alabama\"}" this ill unmarshall with this way map[string]interface{}  So when i use REFLECT for both cases its return string. how can i do it in generic way

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
result:=map[string]interface{} {
   "data": apiResponse,
   "statusCode": 200,
}
out, err:=json.Marshal(result)
```

Comment: thanks for answer but still output exactly same as i mentioned in question

Comment: Then your api response is a string. Unmarshal it to an interface{}.

Comment: when i tried like this  ---->   var result map[string]interface{}
  json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &result)             its not Unmarshal because api response has array, i need to mark array map, but what if my respnse is single json object. how can i mark do it in generic way

Comment: If this is not working, then there is something else wrong. Post your code where you did this, and the output you got

Comment: var result []map[string]interface{}
  json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &result)
  out, err := json.Marshal(result)       if i mark map array then its Unmarshal it

Comment: Edit your question to show the relevant code.